# String read from file vs variable

Tags: c++, string, unicode

If i have a `.txt` file with the string **\u001c\]A\u0012B\u0016** in it and I read it using `ifstream` and store it in `std::string str1;` like this:

```
if (file.is_open())
{
    std::string str1;
    std::getline(file, str1);
}
```

Then when I `std::cout << str1 << "len: " << str1.length();` it will print:

**\u001c\]A\u0012B\u0016 len: 23** .

But if a variable is hardcoded like this: `std::string str2 = "\u001c\\]A\u0012B\u0016";` and then printed like:

```
std::cout << str2 << "len: " << str2.length();
```

This will be printed:

**]AB len: 7**  **note you dont see all 7 characters as they are not valid

I would need to make the string read from file behave like the normal string variable. So `str1` will print the way `str2` does.

**If this is possible I would like to know how it can be done**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: How did you read from the file?

Comment: i updated the question @πάνταῥεῖ